# how to rename all files in folder to HH_MM_SS?

Tags: python

I want to change the file name to hh_mm_ss sequentially every 1 second.  example:
00_59_57.jpg
00_59_58.jpg
00_59_59.jpg
01_00_00.jpg

Comment: Please, check [ask]. You tell us what you want to achieve (although a lot more detail is needed - e.g. in what order you will rename the files), but didn't show what have you tried and explain what problem you cannot solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you!

```
import os
import time

# Time now
time_now = (time.strftime("%H_%M_%S"))

# Time with one second more
time_now_plus_one = (time.strftime("%H_%M_%S", time.localtime(time.time() + 1)))

# Names of the files
old_name = "./"+time_now+".jpg"
new_name = "./"+time_now_plus_one+".jpg"

# Renaming the file
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it's not working, so I just rename with list from text file. Thanks 